# android get key press programmatically

Tags: android, save, keylogger

I want to know which key has been pressed in android keyboard. For example, if a is pressed {a}, I want to show value {a} in screen with toast ?

i want using broadcastreciever or background service

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)` in your Activity:

```
@Override
   public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
      Log.i("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
   return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: thanks liviu , but how to use this code to background service ??

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    KeyEvent event;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dispatchKeyEvent(event);

    }

    @Override
       public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
          Log.i("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
       return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }



}
```

When I run this code, the keyboard app crashes. A dialog with message posted below is displayed.

> Unfortunately,keyboard has stopped

Comment: thanks tomrozb , but how to use this code to background service ??

Comment: You didn't initialize event, so it is null